# Shopping Cart: Paypal OR Google Checkout options working but not BOTH

Tags: javascript, paypal, shopping-cart, blogger, google-checkout

The problem is that I have a complete working shopping cart but it's not coded for BOTH Paypal and Google Checkout, it's coded for one or the other.

Demo of shopping cart set to Paypal checkout: http://shoppingcart-bthub.blogspot.com/

The javascript in the demo above: http://shopppingcart.googlecode.com/files/simplecart.js

As you can see in the javascript above, it has options of Paypal OR Google checkout, hence:

```
var NextId=1,Custom="Custom",GoogleCheckout="GoogleCheckout",PayPal="PayPal",Email="Email",
```

And within the "/head" you can pick your option by doing this:

```
<script src='http://shopppingcart.googlecode.com/files/simplecart.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
simpleCart.email = "example@gmail.com";
simpleCart.checkoutTo = PayPal;
simpleCart.currency = USD;

simpleCart.cartHeaders = ["thumb_image" , "Quantity_input" ,   "Total", "remove" ]; 
</script>
```

However, you can't pick BOTH options. Hence there is only one checkout button that links to the javascript:

```
<a class='simpleCart_checkout' href='javascript:;'>Checkout</a>
```

Does anyone have any good idea on how to get BOTH checkout options working?

P.S. I have skills in HTML, CSS, jQuery but limited javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from: [SimpleCart-JS GitHub](https://github.com/wojodesign/simplecart-js/issues/69)

*comment* out all your `checkoutTo`:

```
// simpleCart.checkoutTo = GoogleCheckout;
```

and add a function: I created an easy function:

```
function passPaypal(){ simpleCart.checkoutTo = PayPal; } function passGoogle(){ simpleCart.checkoutTo = GoogleCheckout; }
```

And then my checkout options:

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_checkout" onclick="passPaypal();" >checkoutpaypal</a>

<a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_checkout" onclick="passGoogle();" >checkoutgoogle</a>
```

Comment: Sweet! Where within the javascript should I place the new "function" string above?

Comment: where the line // simpleCart.checkoutTo = GoogleCheckout; is